# Keep AWS secret key out of Javascript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, secret-key

I have a web app that is using AWS Lambda and API Gateway (protected by IAM) for the backend, the front end is built using React. I am trying to figure out what the best way is to keep the AWS Secret Key out of the production Javascript code, so far I can't find anything better than just obfuscating the key but that doesn't really solve anything.

So far in development I am using the apigClient and hard coding both the access key and the secret key.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe create a json file with your aws creditentials in it ? Then in your code, you import the file and get what you want

Comment: I hope you mean in the *backend* code, that definitely shouldn't be in the React app. As you're on AMS you could look into [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) to help manage those secrets.

Comment: We had a similar headache. In the end we used Cognito. If your app authenticates with Cognito AWS can give it federated access to whatever you decide it needs. Of course, then you have the problem of getting the Cognito user name and pwd to your app. But if it's a service users subscribe to then that can be taken care of at registration, I guess, with an email. When that user's need for access ends delete their Cognito user. No need for any AWS keys anywhere. Don't know if any of this helps or I'm wide of the mark? Cheers, Adam.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has an interface for environmental variables in their apps. It looks like these are the [docs for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html). You should put any credentials in that interface and then you should be able to access them in your Lambda function. Locally, you can use an npm like [dot-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and use an `.env` file to access your environmental variables. Or you can just add them in your command line. If you are going to use an `.env` file it is VERY IMPORTANT that your ignore that file in your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you include in your javascript code will be readable in the browser, if someone inspects the source code of your final bundle.

If you want to be 100% sure your secret key remains hidden, you should do this authentication in the backend.

However, you can keep the secret keys out of the repo by setting them up as env variables.